# ./src/index.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-5-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this error when I `npm start` my react project. anyone able to solve this?

```
./src/index.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-5-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--6-oneOf-5-3!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-5-4!./src/index.scss) Module not found: Can't resolve './assets/scss/flag-icon
```

Comment: Did you solve this? Same here!

Comment: i delete the whole project and install from github and it works. i cant figure out whats wrong

Comment: I had issue like you, i update nodejs version to latest and it work for me!

Answer (score 12):

```
npm uninstall node-sass;

npm install node-sass@4.14.1
```

Comment: If I could upvote this 10 times, I would! 

Comment: I don't know why this worked. I had: `"node-sass": "^4.14.1"` already...?

Comment: I get errors when trying to install the above package.

Answer (score 1):

1. Delete your `node_modules` folder
2. Delete `package-lock.json` or `yarn.lock`

from the command line, run

3. `yarn install`
4. `yarn start`

Comment: Please provide more detailed instructions on each step that you can.

Answer (score 1):

Node Sass is now deprecated now so you can try uninstalling it by using this command:

```
npm uninstall node-sass
```

and trying:

```
npm install node-sass
```

This worked for me when I was having issues installing sass on a project using create react app

Answer (score 0):

the error is at the end:

`Module not found: Can't resolve './assets/scss/flag-icon` can you confirm this exists? it's saying it cannot find it

Comment: its working all along and today i delete my node_module and do a bunch of audit fix and npm fund it this error pop up.

Answer (score 0):

Node Sass is now deprecated now so you can try uninstalling it by using this command:

```
npm uninstall node-sass
```

and trying:

```
npm install --save-dev sass
```

This worked for me when I was having issues installing sass on a project using create react app

Answer (score 0):

Type the following command:

```
npm rebuild node-sass
```

I hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by installing a previous version of node in my case version 14.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I had this same error. To fix this, I had to navigate to

```
node_modules/resolve-url-loader

open

index.js
```

and under var options change removeCR from "false" to "true".

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Answer (score -4):

I had the same issue and I fixed by doing:

```
npm audit fix --force
```

and it works!